# How should I create this new page? JSP or servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am completely new to web development and I would like some help please. I am doing a payroll system web application project using Java Eclipse EE, tomcat server and mysql. I used a tutorial and managed to create the login interface below. So right now, when i click enter my login details and click login (at localhost:8080/Payroll) I want it to go to a web page (which I have no idea how to create) and display a list of buttons (any random buttons which I can later rename). Can someone please help me. I have no idea about how to use .JSP, .html, .java and I am really confused about how these file types will help me get what I want. Please help someone, I just want the login button to redirect to a web page with buttons on it. Thank you.

Login.java (Servlet)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String employee_id = request.getParameter("employee_id");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if(Validate.checkUser(employee_id, password)) { 
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("**SOME FILE NAME HERE TO REDIRECT TO?**");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
       out.println("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
       RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
       rs.include(request, response);
    }
}  


    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
<h3>
Employee Login
</h3>
 <b>Employee ID:</b> <br>
 <input type="text"name="employee_id" size="20"><br><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input type="password" name="password" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Validate.java (class file)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Validate
{
    public static boolean checkUser(String employee_id, String password)
    {
        boolean st = false;
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ?");
            ps.setString(1, employee_id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
             st = rs.next();

         }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
             return st;                 
      }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your index.html is already a "page with buttons" this seems to work for you.

However, if your page will include dynamic data, you're better of with jsp.

You might want to start by setting the username into the session and go display that in jsp:

```
    request.setAttribute("user", employee_id);
    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("stackoverflow.jsp");
    rs.forward(request, response);
```

And in stackoverflow.jsp

```
  <h2><%= request.getAttribute("user") %></h2>
```

Now compare calling the jsp directly and when invoked through login...

Make sure to read on MVC in web projects and consider using a framework (like Spring) once you have a feel for the concepts.

Some notes on your code:

You don't ever close Connection, Statement, ResultSet. Consider a connection pool and try-with-resource:

```
public static boolean checkUser(String employee_id, String password)
{
    boolean st = false;
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
           PreparedStatement ps = 
                con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ?")) {
        ps.setString(1, employee_id);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        try(ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery()) {
          return rs.next();
        }
     }catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return false;                 
  }
```

Comment: "You might want to start by setting the username into the session and go display that in jsp." Can you please assist me on how to do this?